# How to prevent a style sheet from loading in mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, css, ipad, mobile

I wish to prevent a series of animations from taking place in smartphones and tablets. The most simple solution I can think of is to simply move these animations CSS into a separate style sheet and somehow prevent this style sheet from loading in all smartphones and tablets.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

1. Please, no Media Queries addressing the screen width (this is far from precise, as some tablets are as wide as some laptops).
2. Addressing touch devices would be a solution I could live with although not perfect as some laptops have this feature.
3. Ideal solution, I think, would be to address mobile Browsers and Operating Systems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **media queries** in your css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

E.G:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:991px){
   /*insert here all the css you want to be load ONLY on devices below 991px*/
}
```

If you want to **divide your CSS in two sheets** then you can set this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="exmaple.css" media="(min-width: 991px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**EDIT:**

In your case, an option is to set a media query like this one:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:1200px){
/*insert here those CSS animations.*/
/*they will only take effect on devices above 1200px*/
}
```

Of course you can set **any resolution** and **use min-width and max-width** as you want.

Comment: @DavidMartins Then you can use some library as Modernizr to detect is the device is touchable or not. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot Nancho. I just don't think media queries are the best solution for this as some tablets are as wide in screen as some laptops. I think the solution for this must be something like "navigator.platform" or "user agent", but I'm not familiar with the use of these.

Comment: @DavidMartins Take a look to the comment above you.

Comment: Hi Nancho, I apreciate your help, I never used Modernizr though, from what I just read it seams I'm suppose to install Modernizr and then use some javascript to achieve what I want, but I don't know what the syntax would look like. Also It seams that addressing touch devices is not the best solution after all as there are laptops with this feature. Probably the best solution would be to address Android, webOS, iPhone, iPad, iPod, BlackBerry, IEMobile, Opera Mini, etc...

Comment: I neither used it, only heard of it. I guess it's all explained in their documentation. After this point I dont have enough knowledge to keep helping you. Sorry and luck! @DavidMartins

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the offending CSS in a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) excluding small devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I just don't think media queries are the best solution for this as some tablets are as wide in screen as some laptops. I think the solution for this must be something like "navigator.platform" or "user agent", but I'm not familiar with the use of these.